# TextInputEditText Error

Tags: android, xml

Error Rendering in TextInputLayout in API 21 in studio.  However it is working perfect in API level 23. In real time working perfect on both

```
 The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText (Open Class, Show  Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  
Exception Details java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index  out of range: 0   at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)   at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils_Delegate.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils_Delegate.java:47)   at  com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:88)   at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getInt(BridgeTypedArray.java:204)   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1051)   at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:65)   at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:61)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:62)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:58)   at android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText.<init>(TextInputEditText.java:39)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
```

I am just taking basic details of a person in this . For which I have used various EditText....................................................................................................................................

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/background_first">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/update_details_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="@string/u_fields"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/navy_blue"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/navy_blue"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/u_fields_text1"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.design.widget.EditText
                    android:id="@+id/update_first_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:hint="@string/first_name_hint"
                    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/update_first_name_action"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
                <requestFocus/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1">
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.design.widget.EditText
                    android:id="@+id/update_last_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:hint="@string/last_name_hint"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/update_last_name_action"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:maxLength="15"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/update_button"
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/done"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: please put your code here

Comment: please follow this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

Comment: Why I am getting this in API Level 21.   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index  out of range: 0. However when i run the app in API Level 21 in my mobile ,i don;t find any problem. Does TextInputEditText also supports lower api than 23.2.0?

Answer (score 1):

RisingSun for your information the **TextInputEditText**  is added in **version 23.2.0** hence it can not support below 23.2.0 version..

for more follow this link

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText.html

Comment: However if i use EditText alone then i get this error The following classes could not be found:
- EditText (Fix Build Path, Edit XML) android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not find color resource matching value 0x7F0C004F (resolved name: navy_blue) in current configuration.   at android.content.res.BridgeResources.throwException(BridgeResources.java:709)